# Blackberry-Alarm code sample

Tags: blackberry

i am new to Blackberry application development i want to set alarm for particular time in my application.At the time of Alarm my application wants to open can any one give a sample?Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Check the API documentation for [net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html) under "Schedule an application to run later".